# Make JobScheduler and JobInfo.Builder run at a specific and exact time?

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app where I send notifications at a specific time. I was looking at the JobScheduler API with the JobInfo.Builder but when I looked at this page:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html

I see that the setPeriodic method says:

> Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval, not
>   more than once per period. You have no control over when within this
>   interval this job will be executed

So it seems like this method will randomly do the task within the set time.

How can I use the JobScheduler API to set a task to happen at an exact time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How can I use the JobScheduler API to set a task to happen at an exact time?

You don't. `JobScheduler` is specifically designed for inexact timing, so it can combine jobs from multiple apps, to try to reduce power consumption.

Your best option will be `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Awesome thanks...but also not awesome because AlamrManager doesn't persist through system reboots like JobScheduler does...

Comment: @Albert: Correct. You would need to register an `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` to re-establish your alarm on a reboot.

Comment: I think im just going to use one of these libraries https://github.com/evernote/android-job https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue

Comment: @Albert: Of the two, I would lean towards the Evernote one, if your `minSdkVersion` is below 21. AFAICT, Yigit's library requires the proprietary `GcmNetworkManager` to support Android 4.4 and below, while Evernote's uses `AlarmManager`.

Comment: The evernote android job is again an abstraction from `JobScheduler` ergo inexact.

Comment: @EugenPechanec: Oh, right. My apologies, I lost the plot on my earlier comment. That being said, Yigit's library will be no better in that regard, AFAIK.

Comment: So what you are saying is that those libraries won't be helpful in terms of persisting the job through reboot, and having an exact timing? Because going through the github pages it seems like those libraries do that... @CommonsWare

Comment: @Albert: It's possible that the Evernote one falls back to `AlarmManager` right away for the `setExact()` job structure. You would have to check the implementation. I don't see where Yigit's library allows for any type of scheduling, other than a simple delay construct.

Comment: damn i spent like 30 minutes trying to configure the yigit library, it was pretty confusing shoulda used evernote one

Answer (score 0):

You can use setMinimumLatency() and setOverrideDeadline() to scheduler job